# c# regex get every instance of start to end char

Tags: c#, regex

In c#, I'm struggling to create a regex that will pick up each instance of a start -> end character. 
start char = #
end char = ##

text to evaluate:
blah blah blah blah #*instance1 regex needs to pick this up*## blahblah #*instance2 regex needs to # ignore hashes# within until it gets to the end*##

So i want it to find every instance that starts with "#" and ends with "##" ignoring other hashes in between.

This needs to work across paragraphs of text and to ignore newlines, carriage returns etc. I just want everything between the start # and the end ## for each instance of that pattern.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the regex below:

```
/#.*?##/g
```

Note That: `?` quantifier  makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible.

---

For multiline operation

```
/#(.|\s)*?##/gm
```

For C#

```
Regex.Match(input, "#(.|\s)*?##", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: Worked fine in a regex tester but not in c# :(

var bodyRegex = new Regex(@"/#(.|\s)*?##/gm");
var bodyMatches = bodyRegex.Matches(newEmail.EmailBody);

That returns no matches, but the newEmail.EmailBody defo has the pattern #blahblah## repeated within it.

Comment: why do I need to delete this answer? why is it requested?